# editing a saved ppt file in xml format with js

Tags: javascript, xml, base64, powerpoint

So I have a saved xml template file. This file is basically a ppt file that was saved as XML. I'm trying to ajax that file in and then base 64 encode it in order to try to promt the user to download that xml file. My theory is that I can parse the xml file, edit it and then prompt the user to download it. Once the user has downloaded the file he/she can open it in ppt. This is my code so far
http://jsfiddle.net/NKa5T/
I've managed to get the prompt for a ppt file but it is a blank ppt file not one that has the containing xml in it.
And here is the [gitHub repo](https://github.com/climboid/jsToPPT) if you want to have it working with the download of the xml file.

Comment: Have you heard of pptx files?

Comment: You cannot download files from local Javascript, I think. You'll download from the server.

Comment: The file is an xml file that just so happens to have all the data needed to run as a ppt. I think I'm going to try to serve the mime type just as xml but have the download extension be .ppt... see if that works

Comment: What ppt are you talking about, actually?

Comment: I have a ppt file that was saved as xml. I'm trying to prompt the user to download that xml file. If the user opens it with powerpoint the presentation will/should open.

Comment: Ah, PowerPoint indeed. Just wanted to check. How does PowerPoint know it can read it? PowerPoint cannot read just any XML.

Comment: Exactly, there is something in the XML that tells powerpoint that its ok. Some kind of meta info